# video downloads preview in opencart

Tags: url, download, opencart

I want to add play button in opencart downloads section for video files. For that I need a static url of that video file

currently I am able to retrieve dynamic video URL like

http://www.abc.xx/index.php?route=account/download/download&order_download_id=2269 which i cannot pass to video player

I want to get www.abc.xx/downloads/xyz.mp4

or is their is another way to play video file with existing Dynamic URL??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing the `order_download_id` you should be able to retrieve the download file information before displaying the URL for download. Basically what you need to do is to adjust the `index()` action (method) of `catalog/controller/account/download.php` to retrieve the download file information for each `order_download_id` customer has access to the same way as it is done in the `download()` action (still same file).

Then if the file is video instead of displaying the download URL you can now display the required path to video file for the video player.